# Errors when converting a large list to a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

My problem is pretty strange:

I have a dataframe df  which looks like: ( 1 million of rows)

```
ColA  ColB   ColV  ..   ColX 
...  ...    ....    ...
```

I have a function which uses a dataframe to do some processing and converting a set of values to a list and then I convert that list to a dataframe.

```
def funcProc(df,..):
  l=[] 
  mydf = df.copy() 
  for i in df.ColA:    
     #do something to get some val     
     l.append(val)

  mydf['ColAA'] = pd.DataFrame(l)
  return mydf
```

However, I am always seeing that the last 10/11 rows are giving me Nan values. That should not be the case.  I have checked my list ( by returning and printing the list only from the function). That looks fine.

Need some help in understanding the logical issue.

Comment: When you append the list as a new column, don't convert it to a dataframe first - `mydf['ColAA'] = l`

Comment: Thanks.. So what should I do then?

Comment: You want to convert to series irst and then choose the values?

Comment: Why don't you use `.apply()`? `mydf['ColAA']=df.ColA.apply(do_something_to_get_some_val)`. No loops, no copies...